# I'm not able to get API response when the state is changed

Tags: reactjs

I built a simple app that is pulling data from movies API. When the user type something in the input, the state URL should be updated with the value from the input. Everything works fine until the button is clicked ("hendleSubmit" method gets called) and I see my error message "Something went wrong TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource." Can someone help me figure this out?

[This is link to my Codepen](https://codepen.io/TonyAntonov/pen/xmoNpp?editors=0011)

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
     this.state = {
       data: [],
       url: ""
     } 
    }
  // Method to call APIs
   getApiResponse() {
     console.log(this.state.url);
    fetch(this.state.url)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => {
        const results = result["Search"];
             this.setState({
                    data: results
                })
       console.log("Data result: " + results);
            })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Something went wrong ' + error);
      })
   }
    componentDidMount(){ 
      console.log("The Form component has been mounted");
    }
  
  handleChange = (event) => {
    const {value} = event.target;
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      url: 'https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=thewdb&s=' + value
    })
  }   
  handleSubmit = () => {
    return this.getApiResponse();
    }

  render(){
    console.log("STATE URL: " + this.state.url);
    const { data } = this.state;

    return(
    <div className="container">
        <h3 className="text-center">Test Page</h3>
        <Table movieData={data}/>
        <Form handleChange={this.handleChange}
              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
    </div>
    )
  }
}

class Table extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const {movieData} = this.props;
    return(
    <table className="table table-dark table-hover">
      <TableHeader />
      <TableBody movieData={movieData} />  
    </table>  
    )
  }
}
class Form extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const { handleChange, handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return(
     
    <form action="" method="" className="form-inline">
    <input name="movieName" type="text" placeholder="Enter search" onChange={handleChange}/>
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>search</button>
    </form>
   
    )
  }
}

const TableHeader = () => {
  return(
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  )
}

const TableBody = (props) => {
  const rows = props.movieData.map((row, index) => {
    console.log(row);
    return(
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{row.Title}</td>
        <td>{row.Year}</td>
        <td>{row.imdbID}</td>
      </tr>  
    )
  })
  
  return(
  <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Anton App</title>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the default onSubmit action.  Your problem is that after you initiate the request, the default form submit action runs and reloads your page.

Change handleSubmit to look like this:

```
handleSubmit = ev => {
  ev.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
  return this.getApiResponse();
}
```